# How can I express a rotation with just a 4D vector?

Tags: 3d, rotation, scenekit

I am learning how to play with SceneKit, and I am deeply confused with methods/properties that involve a `SCNVector4`, such as `SCNPhysicsBody.applyTorque` and `SCNNode.rotation`. Apparently, you can express a rotation of a 3D object with just 4 values. I do not understand why this is at all.

I searched online for "express 3d rotation with 4d vector" and found lots of stuff about rotations in 4D space, which is not what I want. I also see a lot of webpages that talk about sin and cos, but I failed to understand what they mean. My knowledge of sin and cos is only limited to finding the angles/side lengths of right angled triangles.

In my mind, a rotation of a 3D object needs to be expressed with 7 values i.e. a 7D vector:

- 3 values for the position of one end of the rotation axis
- 3 values for the position of the other end of the rotation axis
- 1 value for the angle you rotate by

I think that I understood 2D rotation in SpriteKit pretty well: each node has an anchor point and so the rotation property is just how many radians about the anchor. However, I can't find such an anchor point in `SCNNode`. When I look up "anchor point scnnode" I get stuff about `ARSCNNode` which is not what I want.

I also looked at [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/146177/scene-kit-tutorial-swift-part-3-physics-2), which says:

> The x-, y- and z-components determine the rotation axis, while the w-component determines the rotation angle, that is, the magnitude of the torque.

How can just the x, y, z components specify the rotation axis?

Can you explain how I can wrap my head around this craziness?

Comment: IIRC you should only need three coordinates to uniquely specify a rotation (assuming the rotation axis includes the origin) - for example, two angles to specify the rotation axis, and one to specify the rotation angle.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions for more info.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I can kind of get how you express the rotation axis with two angles if I try really hard. I guess now the question becomes "where on the node is the 'origin'" and "how do you express 2 angles with 3 scalars"...

Comment: Well, for a start you only need two scalars to specify two angles :)  The choice of origin is up to you - it's basically how you choose to model your coordinate system.  You can express a rotation around something other than the model by first applying a translation, then the rotation, and then the opposite translation.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth If I am writing my own game engine, then I suppose I can specify my own origin... But I am using SceneKit, so I have to stick with its APIs. And somehow the `applyTorque` method takes a `SCNVector4`. This is what I am trying to understand.

Comment: Alas I know nothing about SceneKit :/  My comment is really just to address the "need 7 values" thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that I could write a little "SceneKit console" thing to test out what each of the four values in the vector does.

I put a textfield, a button and a `SCNView` into a view controller's view. In the scene, I added a ground node with a kinematic physics body and a box node with a dynamic physics body. I then made it so that when the button is tapped, the command entered in the text field would run. This is how I parsed the command:

```
func executeCommand(_ command: String) {
    let parts = command.components(separatedBy: " ")
    let node: SCNNode
    guard let nodeString = parts.first else { return }
    switch nodeString {
    case "box": node = box
    case "ground": node = ground
    default: return
    }
    guard let selector = parts.dropFirst().first else { return }
    switch selector {
    case "applyTorque":
        if parts.count == 6 {
            let x = Double(parts[2])!
            let y = Double(parts[3])!
            let z = Double(parts[4])!
            let w = Double(parts[5])!
            let direction = SCNVector4(x, y, z, w)
            node.physicsBody?.applyTorque(direction, asImpulse: true)
        }
    // I decided to add other commands as well, but they're irrelevant so I left them out
    default: break
    }
}
```

Now, I tried entering commands like `box applyTorque 1 0 0 1` and saw what happened. Here are my findings:

- The first three values represent how much the node should be rotated about the x, y, and z axes respectively.
- The last value seem to be like an "overall force". If I set this to 0 the box just wouldn't move regardless of what the other values are.
- Rotation about the y axis seems "easier". A Y value of 1 can "spin" the cube 90 degrees, but an X value of 1 can only raise the box up from one side a little bit.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Not sure how this answers (or is even relevant to) your question about the number of values required to specify a rotation. Besides this also raises the question of why the `x = 1` case only raises the box up a little bit, which the above does not answer.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog at least I now have a an idea of what each of the four values mean, which is what I wanted to know in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

> I guess now the question becomes "where on the node is the 'origin'"

That is given by (minus the) `SCNNode.position` ([source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1408026-position)). This is the translation applied to it with respect to its parent node.

> ...  and "how do you express 2 angles with 3 scalars" ...

According to [Euler's Displacement Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersDisplacementTheorem.html), *any* rotation in 3D can be represented by an axis and a rotation angle. These can in turn be stored as:

1. Either (as `@OliverCharlesworth` suggested) 2 spherical polar angles specifying the axis and another the rotation angle
2. Or a vector parallel to the axis with magnitude proportional to the *clockwise* (or anti-clockwise) rotation around it; this is e.g. typically how angular velocity is represented

SceneKit merely uses a 4D vector to avoid having to re-compute the axis in Cartesian coordinates (needed for (1)) or retrieve the angle (for (2)).

> In my mind, a rotation of a 3D object needs to be expressed with 7
>   values i.e. a 7D vector:
>
> - 3 values for the position of one end of the rotation axis
> - 3 values for the position of the other end of the rotation axis
> - 1 value for the angle you rotate by

Here lies the problem: you are confusing two definitions of the word "axis", which can be either:

- A fixed line in space, e.g. the X-axis
- The common *direction* of a family of lines parallel to each other

By convention the second one is used for specifying rotations. The center of this rotation is the central position of the node (often the midpoint of its AABB).

Comment: I still don't quite understand the axis bit. What do I put for the first three values if I want to e.g. use the diagonal of a cube node as the axis? So the origin of any node is the origin of the root node? Did I understand this part correctly?

Comment: To answer your 1st question, the first three values are the **normalized** XYZ components of the rotation axis (or "direction" if you will), such that the 4th component represents a clockwise rotation around it. So they could be e.g. `1/sqrt(3), 1/sqrt(3), 1/sqrt(3)` for the axis through the positive XYZ corner of the cube.

Comment: To answer the 2nd one, the *origin* (or its coordinate representation, to be more precise; math gurus please have mercy) of a node depends on the **reference frame**. In the parent node's frame, the origin of the child node is its position. In the node's *own* frame, the origin is of course just (0, 0, 0).

Comment: Okay, but where on the node is (0,0,0)? Centre?

Comment: I think you still don't understand the idea of *reference frames*. The actual position of the coordinates (0, 0, 0) depends which node you are observing; to repeat my previous comment, (0, 0, 0) is the position of a node *from the point-of-perspective of its parent node*.

Comment: Apologies as I should make a slight amendment to the statement in my previous comment: the point (0, 0, 0) in the reference frame of a child node corresponds to the child node's position in the reference frame of its parent node.